# How to migrate customer data from magento 2.3.5 to magento 2.4.2

Tags: magento2

I have a magento store live with magento version 2.3.5 and I have a fresh magento installation for magento 2.4.2. Now my requirement is to move my current customer data to 2.4.2 instance. So how can I migrate those from m2.3.5 to m2.4.2 db?

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: Why you don't upgrade to 2.4.2?

Comment: @SohelRana because client want fresh magento installaton instead of upgrade. Also he is going to import fresh catalog in new instance. So that's why he want only fresh magento but he want to move his customers and sales data to new instance.

Answer (score 0):

**Export:**

- From to Admin sidebar, select System then click Export
- In the Entity Type field, select Customers Main File
- Follow instruction
- You can choose the fields that you want to deport from the file by
  checking the box beside each field. You can also choose your parts
  according to other standards: date of birth, date of purchase and so
  on.
- Then select Continue and save the file on your computer

**Import:**

- From to Admin sidebar, select System then click Import
- In the Entity Type field, choose type of data that you would like to import.(Customers Main File)
- In the Imports Behavior field: Choose Add/Update Complex Data if you
  would like to add new clients; Choose Delete Entities if you would
  like to replace your customer database by another.
- In the File to Import field, select the file to import from your
  computer.
- Click Check Data to complete.